# How to enable radio button in android listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-radiobutton

I want to enable radio button in android listview. I don't want to use any custom adapter to display radio button.

Here is my code:

```java
private String[] items = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
View contentsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trusted_credential_list_container, parent, false);

ListView mList = (ListView) contentsView.findViewById(R.id.cert_list);
mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In xml,

```xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cert_list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

Eventhough I used choiceMode as singleChoice, why radio button is not displaying?

Second type I used without radio button in custom adapter that has only textview:

```java
ListView mList = (ListView) contentsView.findViewById(R.id.cert_list);
mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

/*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);*/

ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = User.getUsers();
// Create the adapter to convert the array to views
CustomUsersAdapter adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfUsers);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here also I tried using `mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` but it is not working

Comment: May I ask why you're not using RecyclerView? ListView is kind of deprecated.

Comment: Because as per the requirement, I should not change the code from ListView to RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

The list item layout that you are using (**android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1**) does not contain a **RadioButton**, which is why you aren't seeing any **RadioButton** in your list.

If you want to display a **RadioButton** for each item in the ListView, you'll need to use a different layout. Android provides a built-in layout for this: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice.

You can replace **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** with **android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice** in your ArrayAdapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, items);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: So this is the only way? No other way? What if I use custom adapter without radio button?

Comment: If you want to use ListView, using a layout with a radio button is the only option. But you can use custom layouts. Open `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` to see how it should look. You can create your own layout resource file, just make sure to use the same IDs.

Comment: @Shadow with custom adapter you can add anything, the sky is the limit. But as you used 'android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1' that's why I suggested 'android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice'. Both are Android default resources for ArrayAdapter.